# Logging access changes to users/roles

Tags: logging

I am attempting to perform logging of access changes of users/roles (access change to items- access viewers, not role change of user) and have attempted using the following events and their remote versions on version 9.3:

- user:updated
- roles:usersAdded/removed
- roles:relationsRemoved
- roles:rolesAdded/removed
- data:updated
- user:runtimerolesupdated

Only event that is getting triggered is user:updated upon entering the access viewer. Changes made using 'assign'/ 'assign security rights'- changing the read/write/rename/create/delete does not trigger the events listed.

Is there an event that I should be using or another approach I should be taking?

Comment: Changes made via the access viewer are stored on the items, it has no bearing on the roles.

Comment: Thanks, that has solved my issues. I am able to use events such as item:saved to progress.